# Problem with {"code":-4061,"msg":"Order's position side does not match user's setting."} while creating futures order on CCTX Binance

Tags: python, binance

I'm trying to create simple future order on CCTX binance exchange using this code and get -4061 problem:

```
import ccxt
import asyncio
import json
import config

exchange = ccxt.binance({
    'apiKey': config.apiKey,
    'secret': config.secret,
    'enableRateLimit': True,
})

exchange.options = {'defaultType': 'future', # or 'margin' or 'spot'
                    'adjustForTimeDifference': True,
                    'newOrderRespType': 'FULL',
                    'defaultTimeInForce': 'GTC'}

markets = exchange.load_markets()

symbol = 'BTC/USDT'
type ='MARKET'
side = 'buy'
amount = 0.001
price = 26000


order = exchange.createOrder(symbol, type, side, amount, price)

open_orders = exchange.fetchOrders('BTC/USDT')
data = json.dumps(open_orders, indent=4, separators=(',', ': ') )
```

```
ccxt.base.errors.ExchangeError: binance {"code":-4061,"msg":"Order's position side does not match user's setting."}
```

I've tried to use several things like:

```
exchange.fapiPrivatePostPositionSideDual ({'dualSidePosition':'true'})
```

or

```
exchange.set_position_mode(hedged=True, symbol=symbol)
```

Or setting my Position setting to Hedge-mode on binance website but nothing have helped me

Comment: check this Order's position side does not match user's setting